# central attachment/file table design

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, database-design

UPDATE:

I have generated below tables from sql server.

here is the screen shots of my design:

[image]

shows the data after combining three tables, getting total of 12 rows
my `request table` has **4 rows** and `attachment table` has **3 rows**

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[attachment](
    [attach_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [process_type_id] [int] NULL,
    [attach_content_type] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [attach_name] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_attachment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [attach_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[process_type](
    [process_type_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [process_type] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_process_type] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [process_type_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[request](
    [request_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [request_desc] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [process_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_request] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [request_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[request_review](
    [review_request_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [review_desc] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [process_type_id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_request_review] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [review_request_Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am busy building a database, and now I have a question about my design.

I have got the following tables:
Customer
Employee
upload_doc

I want to be able to add multiple attachments to Customers, Employees

what is the best design:

design #1

### Upload_doc

```
upload_doc_id (NOT auto generated)
upload_doc_name (uploaded doc name)
upload_content_type 
upload_doc_data (blob)
```

### employee

```
employee_id
first_name
middle_name
last_name
upload_doc_id
```

### customer

```
customer_id
first_name
last_name
upload_doc_id
```

design #2

### Upload_doc

```
upload_doc_id (AUTO generated)
upload_doc_name (uploaded doc name)
upload_content_type 
upload_doc_data (blob)
employee_id
customer_id
```

### employee

```
employee_id
first_name
middle_name
last_name
```

### customer

```
customer_id
first_name
last_name
```

Comment: are you using postgresql or MS SQL, as your question has both tagged

Comment: I'd say neither are great designs. Design 1 doesn't allow you to have multiple documents per employee/customer. Design 2 has redundancy in the Upload_doc table where it will only fill 1 of the 2 link columns.

Comment: I'm not sure what database will choose at the end so that's why I'm targeting both at this point.

Comment: @Tanner: do you have any good design?

Answer (score 0):

Design one, but would make upload_doc_id an auto gen id column.

If you are using MS SQL, I would use FILETABLE instead of blobs.  [Files in MS SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403405.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but my question is more on designing the table.

Comment: I disagree that #1 is a good choice. It does not allow for more than 1 doc per employee.

Comment: in my case I want more than one doc

Answer (score 0):

The info in your question is somewhat limited, but I'll give it a quick attempt. Personally I'd have a common table for personal information like: names and contact info.

Then have a type lookup table that defines what type of person/contact they are: customer / employee.

Then you can link docs to the common person table. Something like the below, which you can run as is:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_person -- common information like name & contact info
    (
      PersonId INT ,
      FirstName VARCHAR(20) ,
      MiddleName VARCHAR(20) ,
      LastName VARCHAR(20) ,
      PersonTypeId INT -- lookup value to person type table
    )
CREATE TABLE #temp_person_type -- determines if they are employees or customer
    (
      PersonTypeId INT ,
      PersonType VARCHAR(10)
    )

CREATE TABLE #temp_employee
    (
      EmployeeId INT ,
      PersonId INT -- linked to person table
      -- other fields would be employee specific
    )

CREATE TABLE #temp_customer
    (
      CustomerId INT ,
      PersonId INT -- linked to person table
    -- other fields would be customer specific
    )

CREATE TABLE #temp_upload_doc
    (
      UploadDocId INT ,
      PersonId INT , -- linked to person table
      DocName VARCHAR(20)
    )

INSERT  INTO #temp_person_type
        ( PersonTypeId, PersonType )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Employee' ),
        ( 2, 'Customer' )

INSERT  INTO #temp_person
        ( PersonId, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, PersonTypeId )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Bob', 'Jon', 'Smith', 1 ),
        ( 2, 'David', '', 'Jones', 1 ),
        ( 3, 'Andy', '', 'Johnson', 2 ),
        ( 4, 'Richard', '', 'Branson', 2 )


INSERT  INTO #temp_customer
        ( CustomerId, PersonId )
VALUES  ( 1, 3 ),
        ( 2, 4 )

INSERT  INTO #temp_employee
        ( EmployeeId, PersonId )
VALUES  ( 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 2 )

INSERT  INTO #temp_upload_doc
        ( UploadDocId, PersonId, DocName )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 'Doc 1' ),
        ( 2, 1, 'Doc 2' ),
        ( 3, 2, 'Doc blah' ),
        ( 4, 3, 'Doc dog' ),
        ( 5, 3, 'Doc images' ),
        ( 6, 4, 'Doc another' ),
        ( 7, 4, 'Doc la la la' )

-- EMPLOYEES AND DOCS
SELECT * 
FROM #temp_person p
INNER JOIN #temp_person_type pt ON pt.PersonTypeId = p.PersonTypeId
INNER JOIN #temp_employee e ON e.PersonId = p.PersonId
INNER JOIN #temp_upload_doc u ON u.PersonId = e.PersonId
WHERE p.PersonTypeId = 1

-- CUSTOMERS AND DOCS
SELECT * 
FROM #temp_person p
INNER JOIN #temp_person_type pt ON pt.PersonTypeId = p.PersonTypeId
INNER JOIN #temp_customer c ON c.PersonId = p.PersonId
INNER JOIN #temp_upload_doc u ON u.PersonId = c.PersonId
WHERE p.PersonTypeId = 2

DROP TABLE #temp_customer
DROP TABLE #temp_employee
DROP TABLE #temp_person
DROP TABLE #temp_upload_doc
DROP TABLE #temp_person_type
```

Comment: agreed that I shouldn't have give you the example of `first_name, last_name` and I do understand how to normalize that table, however based on your design, you think I should have a junction table in this case you have used `temp_person_type` between `upload_tbl` with other tables (employee, customer) ?

Comment: @AbuHamzah person_type is just a lookup table to define the different person types (like an enum). uploads are linked directly to the person table, regardless of who they are. So 1 person can have many documents. The employee and customer tables are simply there to hold any data that is specific to the different entities. Employees may have a start date. Customers may have an account number.

Comment: yes i got that its just a lookup table, let me post my new real design in few mnts.

Comment: please have a look at my new design based on the lookup table, what do you think?